# subselecting and creating in r

Tags: r

Suppose this data set:

```
household_id person_id age_group  
1            1         5  
1            2         3  
1            3         2  
2            1         3  
2            2         5
2            3         1
2            4         1
```

I want to create a new field indicating whether or not the household includes any person of age_group=1 as follows:

```
household_id person_id age_group age_group1  
1            1         5         0  
1            2         3         0
1            3         2         0
2            1         3         1
2            2         5         1
2            3         1         1
2            4         1         1
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ave(t$age_group, t$household_id, FUN=function(x) 1 %in% x)
[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1

> t$age_group1 <- with(t, ave(age_group, household_id, FUN=function(x) 1 %in% x))
> t
  household_id person_id age_group age_group1
1            1         1         5          0
2            1         2         3          0
3            1         3         2          0
4            2         1         3          1
5            2         2         5          1
6            2         3         1          1
7            2         4         1          1
```

Answer (score 3):

A `plyr` solution:

```
require(plyr)
df <- structure(list(household_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
person_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), age_group = c(5L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("household_id", "person_id", 
"age_group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

ddply(df, .(household_id), transform, age_group1 = 0 + any(age_group == 1))

#   household_id person_id age_group age_group1
# 1            1         1         5          0
# 2            1         2         3          0
# 3            1         3         2          0
# 4            2         1         3          1
# 5            2         2         5          1
# 6            2         3         1          1
# 7            2         4         1          1
```

**Edit:** `data.table` alternative:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key="household_id")
dt[, age_group1 := 0 + any(age_group == 1), by=household_id]
```

Comment: what about providing a `data.table` solution here:)?

Comment: +1! thanks really concise! I tried to do it without creating the key , I had a coercion error ` Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('logical').. even and I have error with `dt[, age_group1 := any(age_group == 1), by=household_id]`

Comment: I see my error. I tried `dt[, age_group1 := 0 + any(age_group == 1), by=household_id]` this then `dt[, age_group1 :=  any(age_group == 1), by=household_id]` so I get Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(age_group1, any(age_group == 1)), by = household_id) :...`

Comment: it is in my TODO list! I have toread the manual at least once! maybe my first R package will be with `data.table`

Answer (score 2):

Aftere reading your data

```
dat <- read.table(text = 'household_id person_id age_group  
1            1         5  
1            2         3  
1            3         2  
2            1         3  
2            2         5
2            3         1
2            4         1',head=T)
```

Using `transform` with `ave`(similar to @Mathhew solution) but with more concise sytnax

```
 transform(dat, age_group1  = ave(age_group, household_id, FUN=function(x) any(x==1)))

  household_id person_id age_group age_group1
1            1         1         5          0
2            1         2         3          0
3            1         3         2          0
4            2         1         3          1
5            2         2         5          1
6            2         3         1          1
7            2         4         1          1
```

Comment: @Arun it looks better now I think.

Answer (score 1):

i prefer `sql` for this kinda stuff, since lots of people already know it, it works across languages (sas has `proc sql;`), and it's terribly intuitive  :)

```
# read your data into an object named `x`

# load the sqldf library
library(sqldf)

# create a new household-level table that contains just
# the household id and a 0/1 indicator of
# whether anyone within the household meets your requirement
households <- 
    sqldf( 'select household_id , max( age_group == 1 ) as age_group1 from x group by household_id' )

# merge the new column back on to the original table
x <- merge( x , households )

# view your result
x
```

Answer (score 1):

here's another option that doesn't involve installing any packages ;)

```
# read your data frame into `x`
x <- read.table( text = "household_id person_id age_group  
1            1         5  
1            2         3  
1            3         2  
2            1         3  
2            2         5
2            3         1
2            4         1" , head=TRUE)


# determine the maximum of age_group == 1 within each household id
hhold <- aggregate( age_group == 1 ~ household_id , FUN = max , data = x )

# now just change the name of the second column
names( hhold )[ 2 ] <- 'age_group1'

# merge it back on and you're done
x <- merge( x , hhold )

# look at the result
x
```